# {% if object in cart.products.all %} always show false in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    {{ object }}[![image show html output ][1]][1]
    {{ cart }}
    {{ cart.products.all }}
    {% if object in cart.products.all %}
    IN cart
    {% else %}
    NOT cart
    {%  endif %}
```

{% if object in cart.products.all %}  always show false else statement always prints iphone in queryset,iphone,hi  shows false cant figure out y

Answer (score 0):

cart.products.all is an iterator. You can't use 'in' to check an iterator.

Try this:

```
{% if object in cart.products.filter(pk=object.pk).exists() %}
```

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '(pk=object.pk).exists()' from 'cart.products.filter(pk=object.pk).exists()'